# Best way to work with karate and rabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, karate

Is there a way that I can connect to rabbitMQ using Karate Framework to test if the message post on a topic(manually via rabbitMQ client) is available to be consumed?
I find some examples with Kafka, but it's a lib bit confusing since I new to karate framework!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see this example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1128170638223364097

Comment: @PeterThomas but my program does not use post or get. So, do you have any idea on how I'm supposed to get the the message from RabbitMQ? I just have a ReceiveTopic class that wait for a message to be received.

Comment: so you just start your test with a `karate.listen()` - although I think that it is a wrong strategy, because how are you sure you are going to get a message. if you can't figure this out - please assume this is not supported by karate